# Why don't we extend the naming of powers into higher dimensions?

Tags: exponentiation

This is probably a stupid question.

If 2^2 is known as "Two squared" and 2^3 is "Two cubed", then why do we stop at 2^3? Why do we not call 2^4 "Two tesseracted", and so on?

Comment: I think the word tesseract is rather recent, [apparently originating with Charles Howard Hinton (1853-1907) in the 1880s](https://jeff560.tripod.com/t.html). However, much older literature sometimes referred to 4th and 5th powers as "square-square" and "cube-square" (or "square-cube") I think.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense, as 2^2^2 equals 2^4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could, but don't for several reasons.

- Squares and cubes calculate areas and volumes; in everyday life we
  never encounter the geometric generalizations.
- You can't keep inventing a new word for each dimension. There isn't
  one for hypercubes in dimensions greater than four. So it's not clear
  what your "and so on" should be.
- In higher dimensions mathematicians want the name of the calculation
  to tell you the dimension, so you use the dimension itself, not a
  made up word. So "two to the $17$th" for $2^{17}$.
- "Tesseracted" is ugly.